# MYSQL Sequence Function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concurrency, stored-functions

I have created this mysql function

```
delimiter //
create function seq(tag int(10)) returns int
 begin
 update seq set val=last_insert_id(val+1) where tag_code=tag ;
 return last_insert_id();
 end
//
delimiter ;
CREATE TABLE `seq` (
  `tag_code` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `val` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tag_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
insert into seq values(1,100);
insert into seq values(2,100);
```

It is working fine with InnoDb, but at times my function call getting timed out.
I am planning to switch table engine to MyISAM , But I am worrying about 
concurrency issue .i.e parallel call to this function can return same sequence

Did any one did this before?

Answer (score 0):

last_insert_id() function's behaviour is table engine independent. If it could return the same value for 2 independent calls, then it would mean that the autoincrement functionality is broken and 2 records with autoincrement field could potentially have the same value.

Moreover, the value it returns is maintained per connection basis, so the function will return different values for different connections.

Comment: Seems I have to perform stress test, then only I can come up with answer